# how to edit '|' result from sqllite3 using sed command

Tags: sql, sqlite, awk, sed

hey guys so i have this database:

```
id   | item_name   | number_of_store| store_location|
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | margarine | 2              | QLD         |
|  4 | margarine | 2              | NSW         |
|  5 | wine      | 3              | QLD         |
|  6 | wine      | 3              | NSW         |
|  7 | wine      | 3              | NSW         |
|  8 | laptop    | 1              | QLD         |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

i got the result i wanted using the distinct from sqllite3 syntax which are the following:

```
id   | item_name   | number_of_store| store_location|
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | margarine | 2              | QLD         |
|  4 | margarine | 2              | NSW         |
```

syntax are :

```
sqlite3 store.sqlite 'select item_name,number_of_store,store_location from store where item_name = 'margarine'> store.txt
```

but when i saved it to txt i got

```
3|margarine|2|QLD
4|margarine|2|NSW
```

however my desired output in the txt are

```
3,margarine,2,QLD
4,margarine,2,NSW
```

i think i should use SED but not quite sure how to do it

i tried with

```
'|sed 's/|//g' |sed 's/|//g'|sed 's/^//g'|sed 's/$//g'
```

however the result only erase the '|' i'm not too sure how to change it to ','

Comment: I would fix the data being exported.  Going through the data twice seems unnecessarily cumbersome.  Read this:  http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-export-csv/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you should sql itself but as per your request you could use following `sed`.

```
awk '{gsub("|",",")} 1' Input_file
```

Or in `sed`:

```
sed 's#|#,#g'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself use `sed -i.bak` option it will take backup of Input_file and save output into Input_file itself.